# Array de Sockets em C

Tags: c, array, socket

Estou estudando em C e estou criando um programa que troca mensagens entre pc's no estilo cliente/servidor. Criou um array de sockets e coloco-os em threads.

```
 int main ()
  {
    pthread_t *servidor = malloc(sizeof(int*)*2);
    pthread_t gui;
    int porta = 5553;

    void *statusConexao;

    //pthread_create(&gui, NULL, iniciaGui,NULL);


      for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
    pthread_create (&servidor[i], NULL, AtivarServidor,(void *)(porta+i));

   }
  for(int i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
 {
  pthread_join (servidor[i], &statusConexao);
  printf("retorno e: %d\n",(int)statusConexao);
 }
 }
```

O objetivo é que, após a conexão ter sido fechada no lado cliente, a função que cria o servidor na thread retornar 1 quando for chamado pthread_exit() (dentro da funcao AtivarServidor), então com esse retorno reabrir a conexao naquela porta novamente.

Acontece que, com o código que tenho, o retorno só e recebido apos todas as conexões sockets terem sido fechadas, creio que seja pelo fato de estar a função pthread_join dentro de um for, alguem tem uma dica de como posso resolver este problema?